# How to remove packages in Delphi Berlin?

Tags: ide, delphi-10.1-berlin

Unlike in earlier versions of Delphi, in Berlin (v10.1) it now seems to be impossible to permanently delete run-time or IDE packages.  If you un-check them or remove them (from the Component: Install Packages menu option) they reappear when next loading Delphi.

Any advice on how to remove them?

From memory, doing so, can greatly improve the load speed of the Delphi IDE (although caution is needed not to delete used packages).

The closest I have got so far is to un-check a package associated with an Project, but that does not seem to remove the package entirely.  Given that the Install Packages screen has a "remove" button, this behavior seems confusing at best. I have never really understood if the listed packages in the Install Packages screen are supposed to apply to the IDE as a whole or to each separate project.

As an aside, it seems that the same problem applies to Known IDE Packages,.  However these can be disabled by editing the list of Known IDE packages (using Regedit) found at key:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\18.0\Known IDE Packages

To disable a package, put an underscore in front of the "Data" value by using the Modify option.  Be careful not to disable any important packages though. Deleting packages either here or in the Known Packages list does not seem to work.  They get restored each time Delphi is run.  This is different vs. older versions of Delphi. (Perhaps due to the new GetIt package management features?)

Any advice gratefully accepted! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Packages can be (un)loaded on a per-project basis.  Do you have a project loaded in the IDE at the time when you are trying to remove packages?  If so, then the Install dialog is relative to the project, otherwise it is global for the IDE as a whole.

Comment: Thanks Remy - I am able to disable/unload packages for a particular project using the check boxes in the Install Packages screen, but the remove feature no longer works - either for a particular project or globally. This doesn't seem to be as intended. Is this just my setup?

Comment: I would suggest you [file a bug report](http://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.